# Add data to a custom menu button in TinyMCE

Tags: tinymce, tinymce-4

How can I add or associate data to a custom menu button in TinyMCE? My code goes like this:

```
    tinyMCE.init({
        selector: 'textarea',
        toolbar: " example",
        setup: function (ed) {                                
            ed.addButton('example', {
                type: 'menubutton',
                title: 'Insert Latest Newsletter Link',
                icon: false,
                text: 'Insert Latest Newsletter Link',
                menu: [{text: "Insert Link", onclick: function () {
                    //this is where i want to retrieve data that
                    //i associated with my button
                } }]
            });
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

The solution is by using 'value' in the menu object like:

```
editor.addButton( 'gavickpro_tc_button', {
    title: 'My test button',
    type: 'menubutton',
    icon: 'icon gavickpro-own-icon',
    menu: [
        {
            text: 'Menu item I',
            value: 'Text from menu item I',
            onclick: function() {
                editor.insertContent(this.value());
            }
        }
   ]
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  menu:[[object1],[object2],[object3]]
```

displays the object1,object2, object3 in custom button menu